# I have some code, but I don't know how to decode it

Tags: hex

it looks like hex code... (it can be other code) anyway, it is someone's account PW..
how do I decode it? 
I want decoding C code or other programs..
the code i have is this :

```
cb7c3218f1051b2b$c72d8b27d15df9cd7828820d7adc2cceb3e14b9c35d3526638036efa8631eebc:122.46.153.158:1452510156007
01e1811495434703$5537c833a30f83f6645b1c7f4f98824284a18cffd77e16671ef807f55cd6bf0c:112.162.84.36:1452517801693
49cf183fc1f80a2b$58f6a6fe3676e3d9634ac518bf3e7358dc3879a3d01c7139541be2fcdcabc18f:125.177.65.41:1452646507979
6ab4384bf46b191a$fa807a3eb5457e55fa0da1cb768d00314fb0e88e3db829ad67e73f94dadfb974:58.140.228.254:1452906489410
b81243544ad7436b$c9461e4cfc10494272d5ac310938d4c53e7b84b33b3c21959d60c7c9c2f8aa35:175.123.188.192:1452939778425
ae78842c36cc9478$81f93354d49bfcce9cbfb7d09e35e53c54b1ac554fe4982597828f4670c3211d:121.153.189.25:1452939896767
081ceb7b6fd960c1$3976b5d5f4131e0ec69a31c98f61c032db94242896ea233e08205a272f819046:121.159.227.166:1452940209396
f62015dd0f9b3634$d45f89b7d8a4729606943aad29d94b4463dece80c655ff2da259261b87d41993:127.0.0.1:1453184959658
```

that.. on back is IP. I think that does NOT matter...

Comment: How do you not know how to decode your own file? If your answer is "it is not my file" then why are you trying to decode a file containing account passwords that isn't yours? Most likely it is impossible to "decode" the password since this is probably a hash, but again, how do you not know the format of your own file?

Comment: My Friend asked me to.. and it is my friend's file

Comment: Are you sure those are passwords, and not, for example session ids? Anyway, unlikely to get any help here unless you also mention something about the program that uses this file. Assuming it is even possible.

Comment: Format as far as I can figure: <userId(8-bytes)>$<session token/hashed password(32-bytes)>:<ip of last login>:<epoch time of last login>. All the IPs seem to originate in South Korea. Yeah... Not touching this one. Also see answer by tom-w below

Answer (score 3):

You just posted password hashes, together with IP Addresses, to a public web forum.

There may or may not be a way to decode these (which depending on the algorithms used may be impossible or may simply require lots of computing power and guesswork, or rainbow tables or the like to bypass some of that computing power).

But you should not be decoding them, if only because you do not realize that this is a major violation of secure practices.  You should be sending an apology to your friend for grossly violating his system's security by posting a list of password hashes and IP addresses to a public web forum.  And he should be sending a notice to all of these users to update their passwords, and to update their passwords on any other systems where they use the same password.  (Or if they are all his accounts, he should be updating them.)